# SymPy: Interval Math

Tags: sympy, intervals

#### Intro

We have been working on a recent project and have been looking for a suitable system to calculate some values. SymPy was recommended as being a rich mathematical library. However, we have been unable to make it "work" with our project.

The issue we have been struggling with specifically is that many of the values we would be using have been rounded numerous times and are likely susceptible to float errors. To work around this on a previous project, we used [Interval Arithmetic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/interval-arithmetic) for JavaScript to fairly effective use. mpmath for Python appears to be similar, but SymPy not only uses mpmath, but also offers other potentially useful functions we may need in the future.

#### Problem

A sample equation that we have been working on lately is `a = b * (1 + c * d * e)` and we are looking to solve for `e` when all other variables are known. However, some of the variables need to be represented as a range of values as we don't know the exact value, but a small range.

#### Code

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.sets.setexpr import SetExpr

a, b, c, d, e = symbols('a b c d e')

b = 40
c = 1
d = 0.1
a = SetExpr(Interval(45.995, 46.005))
equ = Eq(b * (1 + c * d * e), a)
solveset(equ, e)
```

```
ValueError: The argument '45.995*I' is not comparable.
```

This was just the latest attempt, but I have tried setting domains, setting inequalities for symbols, using `AccumBounds`, and numerous other solutions but I can't help but think that we have completely overlooked something simple.

---

#### Solution

It appears that that using one interval is doable with the code provided by the selected answer, but it doesn't extend to multiple symbols requiring intervals or ranges of values. It appears we will be extending the [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) library to support additional interval functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an intervalmath module in SymPy in the plotting module for some reason. It doesn't subclass Basic though so can't be used directly in an expression. We can however use `lambdify` to substitute it into an expression as

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting.intervalmath import interval

b = 40
c = 1
d = 0.1
a, e = symbols('a, e', real=True)
equ = Eq(b * (1 + c * d * e), a)
sol_e, = solveset(equ, e)

f_e = lambdify(a, sol_e)
int_a = interval(45.995, 46.005)
int_e = f_e(a=int_a)

print(int_e)
```

This gives

```
[1.498750, 1.501250]
```

I don't think the intervalmath module is used much though so there's a good chance it might not fully work in your real problem.

Using sets is probably a better approach and it seems that `imageset` can do this:

```py
In [16]: set_e = imageset(Lambda(a, sol_e), Interval(45.995, 46.005))                                                             

In [17]: set_e                                                                                                                    
Out[17]: [1.49875, 1.50125]
```

I'm not sure how well this works with more than one symbol/interval though.

EDIT: For completeness I'm showing how you would use `intervalmath` with more than one interval:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting.intervalmath import interval

b = 40
d = 0.1
a, c, e = symbols('a, c, e', real=True)
equ = Eq(b * (1 + c * d * e), a)
sol_e, = solveset(equ, e)

f_e = lambdify((a, c), sol_e)
int_a = interval(45.995, 46.005)
int_c = interval(0.95, 1.05)
int_e = f_e(a=int_a, c=int_c)

print(int_e)
```

That gives

```
[1.427381, 1.580263]
```

Comment: This works great for one symbol and my code may have been slightly misleading. I was hoping if I could solve one symbol interval, I'd be able to solve multiples. We are expecting up to 3 intervals (or ranges) out of a ~30 variable equation.

I haven't been able to coerce the imagesets to work for multiple symbols yet. Have any other suggestions on reading material?

Comment: Ideally `imageset((x, y), 1+x+y, Interval(2, 3), Interval(3, 4))` would work here but it doesn't seem to evaluate.

Comment: I see that, and that's a shame. I definitely appreciate your assistance. I believe we are going to choose a different library for our project.

Comment: Yeah fair enough. For completeness I've added an example of using intervalmath with two intervals